# Android: How to come back directly from Gmail app to app's home screen?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my app i am starting the gmail app directly from my app... I want when i press back navigation from action bar, home screen of app will display, instead the gmail inbox... Can any one help me how to navigate back to app's home screen(I don't want to press default back button of os) directly?

Answer (score 1):

You did not write the Gmail app. It is up to the Gmail app's authors to control the behavior of the BACK button or the up affordance in the action bar in the Gmail app. You do not get a vote.

Comment: can we cutomize the way of opening the gmail app so that we give some control for navigate back when pressing back navigation from action bar....

Comment: @ManishKumar: Not by any documented or supported means, and I am not aware of any undocumented/unsupported means either.